# PHP/MySQL and KML, dynamically generated markers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

So I'm working on this Google Maps engine currently that has several alternating pieces:

1) User selects station they want to see, clicks submit

2) Form activates .php that outputs xml for Google Maps

3) Google maps module reloads map with user requested markers from .php

My problem is that I want the form to submit the information, stay on the page, and the Google maps module to refresh and show the new markers. What its actually doing is taking the user to the .php (which of course shows the XML output)!

I've looked into applying AJAX principles to the javascript but nothing I use works, I'm still very inexperienced at this side of web development. Code is below (also my map isn't centering correctly, it's meant to be centering on Washington, DC?):

**HTML/Javascript Code**

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=JS-KEY&sensor=false">   </script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.8951, 77.0367);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  transitLayer.setMap(map);    

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'gmaps.php',
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    showInContentWindow(text);
  });

  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 </script>

</head>

<body>
Pick your station bro
<form name="form" action="gmaps.php" method="POST">
<select name="station">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="McPherson Square">McPherson Square</option>
  <option value="Gallery Place-Chinatown">Gallery Place-Chinatown</option>
  <option value="Metro Center">Metro Center</option>
  <option value="Mount Vernon Square">Mount Vernon Square</option>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</select>
</form>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width:79%; height:100%; float:right"></div>
<div id="content-window" style="width:19%; height:100%; float:right"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$station = $_POST['station']; 

define("DB_SERVER", "some.server.com"); 
define("DB_USER", "some_user"); 
define("DB_PASSWORD", "some_password"); 
define("DB_NAME", "some_db"); 
define("DB_TABLE", "some_table");  


header("Content-type: application/xml"); 

// Print the head of the document 

printf("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> 
<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0\"> 
<Document>");

if ($db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)) { mysqli_select_db($db, DB_NAME); 
$query = " SELECT * FROM markers " ;

// You could add some WHERE statements here to filter the data 
// DESC means newest first 

$query .= " WHERE stations "; 

$query .= "LIKE '$station'";

// Finally query the database data 

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

// Now iterate over all placemarks (rows) 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { 

// This writes out a placemark with some data 
// -- Modify for your case -- 

printf(' <Placemark id="%d"> 
<name>%s</name> 
<Point> 
<coordinates>%f,%f</coordinates> 
<Price>%s</Price>
<Bedrooms>%s</Bedrooms>
<Bathrooms>%s</Bathrooms>
<Distance>%s</Distance>
<Stations>%s</Stations>
</Point> 
</Placemark>', 
htmlspecialchars($row->id), 
htmlspecialchars($row->address),  
htmlspecialchars($row->lng), 
htmlspecialchars($row->lat),
htmlspecialchars($row->price),
htmlspecialchars($row->bedrooms),
htmlspecialchars($row->bathrooms),
htmlspecialchars($row->distance),
htmlspecialchars($row->stations) ); }; 

// Close the database connection 

mysqli_close($db); };

// And finish the document 

printf(" </Document> </kml>");

?>
```

Bear in mind that the form is talking to the PHP and returning the appropriate values that the user selected, the problem lies in getting getting the form submission to remember the data, query the sql database, print the xml and then populate the map with it WITHOUT LEAVING THE PAGE. Also, its worth pointing out that I've gotten the javascript loading the .php file when its static and i put in some values.

Any help is greatly appreciated, please let me know if I haven't been clear!

Thanks,
Logan

Answer (score 0):

Forget about KML/`KmlLayer` and use the drawable objects provided by the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). Use AJAX calls to retrieve the information you need to create the [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) and render them in the callback.

Example:

```
function loadStation(stationId) {
    $.json({
        // Your PHP file / REST API
        url: 'http://foo.bar/api/stations/' + encodeURIComponent(stationId)
    }).done(function (data) {
        // assuming 'map' is a reference to the google map object
        for (var m in data) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
                map: map,
                title: m.title
            });
        }
    });
}

/*
 * TODO: Register an event handler that calls the loadStation() function
 * when the user selects a station
 */
```

In my opinion KML is of a rather static nature, great to store stuff that has been recorded and is not subject to changes.

Comment: I see how that would be able to generate new markers but how would that affect the HTML form? The problem there is when the client submits their station choice, the browser then loads the php file. Any links would be greatly appreciated, thank you!